# Removing event listener after useEffect runs causing scrollIntoView() to never go off?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, react-hooks, use-effect

Here is my code

```
const [isScrollLocked, setIsScrollLocked] = useState(false)

  const handleScroll = (section, scrollLocked) => {
    if (!scrollLocked) {
      document.getElementById(section).scrollIntoView()
      document.querySelector('body').classList.add('overflow-hidden')
      setIsScrollLocked(true)
      setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('overflow-hidden')
        setIsScrollLocked(false)
      }, 1500)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (e) => handleScroll(nextSection, isScrollLocked)

    document.addEventListener('scroll', handler)

    // cleanup callback, that will be called before the effect runs again

    return () => document.removeEventListener('scroll', handler)
  }, [nextSection, isScrollLocked])
```

It seems that the callback cleanup that runs after the useEffect is making it so that the scrollIntoView inside handleScroll never takes place. However if I console.log before or after it fires off. If I remove the callback the scrollIntoView works as normal but I am stacking up thousands of scroll events and crashing my application.

If anybody could spot why the callback cleanup is having this effect and explain it to me I would really like to know.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how your `setTimeout` and `useEffect` are interacting. Your `useEffect` is running everytime `isScrollLocked` changes. Since your `setTimeout` is changing `isScrollLocked`, it makes it look like `useEffect` is running 1.5 seconds later.

Try removing the `isScrollLocked` watcher:

```
  const [isScrollLocked, setIsScrollLocked] = useState(false);

  const handleScroll = (section) => {
    if (!isScrollLocked) {
      document.getElementById(section).scrollIntoView();
      document.querySelector("body").classList.add("overflow-hidden");
      setIsScrollLocked(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("overflow-hidden");
        setIsScrollLocked(false);
      }, 1500);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (e) => handleScroll(nextSection);
    document.addEventListener("scroll", handler);

    // cleanup callback, that will be called before the effect runs again
    return () => document.removeEventListener("scroll", handler);
  });
```

Here's a link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-7n064

Comment: the isScrollLocked is kind of needed since even though I remove the event listener after useEffect runs it will still fire of a bunch of events on a single scroll before the removal takes place. I don't want just a single scroll event to take place. I want to reattach the event after I handle the scroll.

Comment: Don't worry the event listener will still be there after handing scroll. It doesn't remove event listener after useEffect runs, it removes it after the component unmounts. Skip to the componentWillUnmount part in this page: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: It's fine to have one event listener that's firing a bunch of scroll events, that's normal. The reason your app was crashing is because you were adding dozens of event listeners, and each one was firing hundreds of scroll events (which is a problem).

Comment: oh ok I see. I have changed it and it does not seem to make any noticeable difference in my project. It still does not scroll all the way to the section but if I remove the removeEventListener it does but it also fires a ton of events since I am always adding more listeners and eventually crashes.

Comment: Yeah you need to keep the `removeEventListener`. I've provided a demo. I'd check that out and tweak accordingly.

Comment: oh I have checked the demo but in my project I am trying to scroll down entire sections at a time with the scrollIntoView and that is the part that is not working. If you are interested I could show it to you better in the messages?

Comment: oh btw thank you for  your help I understand the useEffect hook a little better now, I thought I needed to add isScrollLocked and nextSection as dependencies but I understand now why I don't have to do that.